# snap snaplets : benefits of warpping a DB package in a snaplet

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I want to run a web API with snap and I am going to use mongoDB. The hackage provides a well designed package named The mongoDB package. What benefits will I get if I use mongoDB package wrapped in a snaplet as opposed to use it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is kind of the same as with using any other library--roughly that you won't have to write the code that the package author put in the package.  I haven't looked at the mongodb snaplets in years, but this will probably be some code to read config data from the config file, set up the DB connections, etc.

Comment: I should have asked, what are the benefits of warpping a library in a snaplet ?
now I know that snap provides ways to read config data and stuff like that.

Comment: The benefits of wrapping in a snaplet are pretty much what is described in the [snaplet tutorial](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/snaplets-tutorial), which is basically: automatic installation of filesystem resources, config file management, and automatically defining routes.